# compare items from different lists

Tags: python, list

I have a function that is a part of hangman, that gets two inputs

```
filter_words_list(words, pattern):
```

I need a way to know that the letter in a word from the words in a specific spot, is identical
to the letter (that is uncovered) in the pattern and that those letters are IN THE SAME PLACE.
also, word and pattern ought to be in the same length

this is what ive tried:

```
def filter_words_list(words, pattern):
    relevant_words = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == len(pattern):
            for i in range(len(word)):
                for j in range(len(pattern)):
                    if word[i] == pattern[j] and i == j:
                        relevant_words.append(word)
print(relevant_words)

filter_words_list(['aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'aaron', 'aback', 'abacus', 
'abaft', 'abalone'],'ab___',))
```

print: not good.. as you can see here:

```
['aaron', 'aback', 'aback', 'abaft', 'abaft']
```

the print I need:

```
['aback', 'abaft']
```

thanks!

Comment: what are you using for input? looks like the top line that is returned only has 1 error which is first aaron. Other match the ABA sequence

Comment: @Austin only words with the same length it seems

Comment: @Austin yeah... one or the other doesn't seem right - code with the `len` check implies it shouldn't be there though.... :)

Comment: hey sry had a slight error there, edited it. anyway - aback and abaft shows, but two times. and also I get aaron (which shouldn't be there)

Answer (score 1):

something like this might work:

```
words = ('aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'aaron', 'aback', 'abacus',
'abaft', 'abalone')

pattern = 'ab___'

def match(word, pattern):

    # also need to match the length?
    # if len(word) != len(pattern):
    #     return False

    for letter, p in zip(word, pattern):
        if p == '_':
            continue
        if letter != p:
            return False
    return True

matches = [word for word in words if match(word, pattern)]
print(matches)
```

it compares one letter of the word against one character of the pattern (using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in order to iterate over those pairs). it ignores if the character of the pattern is `'_'`.

as the function is written now it does not consider the length of either the word or the pattern.

Comment: Beautiful. The key insight for the OP would be to recognize that strings in python are iterables, and can be used in zips as a consequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.` instead of `_` for your missing character then you've basically got a regular expression, eg:

```
import re

words = ['aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'aaron', 'aback', 'abacus', 'abaft', 'abalone']
# starting with ab followed by exactly 3 characters ($ means match end of string)
wanted = [word for word in words if re.match('ab...$')]
#  ['aback', 'abaft']
# starting with ab followed by at least 3 characters (notice no $ here)
wanted2 = [word for word in words if re.match('ab...', word)]
# ['aback', 'abacus', 'abaft', 'abalone']
# starting with ab, followed by any letter, followed by "f", and exactly one letter
wanted3 = [word for word in words if re.match('ab.f.$', word)]
# ['abaft']
# etc...
```

Comment: ...that would have been my go-to as well!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
def filter_words_list(words, pattern):
    relevant_words = []
    pat = pattern.replace("_","")
    for word in words:
        if word.startswith(pat):
            relevant_words.append(word)
    print(relevant_words)

filter_words_list(['aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'aaron', 'aback', 'abacus','abaft', 'abalone'],'ab___',)
```

Output:

```
['aback', 'abacus', 'abaft', 'abalone']
```

Note: Its gonna work only in the case where the pattern is given such as it starts with certain characters. For e.g, it's not gonna work in case if the pattern is "__a_". Please edit your question if you need something like that.

Comment: can you explain the startswitch part and pat? thanks

Comment: Basically, what I am doing is fetching ab from the pattern "ab___". Now we have a method in python called as "startswith" which check if a string starts with the particular string. So in this case it checks if a word starts with "ab". Check out the startswith documentation : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/startswith

Comment: oh so it wouldnt work for a pattern that the string isnt at the start?

Answer (score 0):

This code will filter words that start with supplied pattern and are as long as that pattern (including "_" characters):

```
def filter_words_list(words, pattern):
    pattern_len = len(pattern)
    pattern = pattern.split('_')[0]

    relevant_words = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == pattern_len and word.startswith(pattern):
            relevant_words.append(word)

    return relevant_words

words = ['aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'aaron', 'aback', 'abacus', 'abaft', 'abalone']
pattern = 'ab___'
print(filter_words_list(words, pattern)) # ['aback', 'abaft']
```

Comment: can you explain the split part and the startswitch ?

Comment: I used split here to remove part with "_" characters and have pure pattern, to later check if word starts with it.

Comment: what if I want not only that it will start with, but will have it and only it ? for example, the words: catch fetch hatch, tache the pattern is __tc_ so the output will be catch fetch and hatch (withuot tache)