# compare specific string to a word python

Tags: python, string, list, cpu-word

say I have a certain string and a list of strings.
I would like to append to a new list all the words from the list (of strings)
that are exactly like the pattern 
for **example**:

```
list of strings = ['string1','string2'...] 
pattern =__letter__letter_ ('_c__ye_' for instance)
```

I need to add all strings that are made up of the same letters in the same places as the pattern, and has the same length.
so for instance:

```
new_list = ['aczxyep','zcisyef'...]
```

I have tried this:

```
def pattern_word_equality(words,pattern):
list1 = []
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        if letter in pattern:
            list1.append(word)
return list1
```

help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: more hangman homework? :) Someone asked this yesterday too funnily enough.

Comment: haha it was me but the question wasnt specific enough anyway..

Comment: oh! did the solution not work for you?

Comment: Noo.. I mean the nice people tried to help but I gave an example that made it seem like the situation isnt exactly what it was. (I gave an example for a pattern that STARTS with letters, though it is actually a random pattern)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242554/10618540 posted there will work the same, doesnt matter if the string didnt start with it.

Comment: you should mark his answer as accepted in that last question (if it works for you. it SHOULD i think), and should ideally close this one off as a duplicate.

Comment: it kinda didnt cause Im calling the function and giving it the words and the pattern and not setting the words and pattern in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760186/simple-python-hangman-game

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is as simple as **_c__ye_**, then you can look for the characters in the specific positions:

```
words = ['aczxyep', 'cxxye', 'zcisyef', 'abcdefg']
result1 = list(filter(lambda w: w[1] == 'c' and w[4:6] == 'ye', words))
```

If your pattern is getting more complex, then you can start using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html):

```
pat = re.compile("^.c..ye.$")
result2 = list(filter(lambda w: pat.match(w), words))
```

Output:

```
print(result1) # ['aczxyep', 'zcisyef']
print(result2) # ['aczxyep', 'zcisyef']
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
words = ['aczxyep', 'cxxye', 'zcisyef', 'abcdefg']
pattern = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    if (words[i])[1].lower() == 'c' and (words[i])[4:6].lower() == 'ye':
        pattern.append(words[i])
print(pattern)
```

You start by defining the words and pattern lists. Then you loop around for the amount of items in `words` by using `len(words)`. You then find whether the `i` item number is follows the pattern by seeing if the second letter is c and the 5th and 6th letters are y and e. If this is true then it appends that word onto pattern and it prints them all out at the end.